# Hexagon grid - paths incorrect

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, queue, hexagonal-tiles

I am writing a program that uses a hexagon map (obviously in the output seen below it appears as a square, but the numbers will make sense for a hexagon shape) to generate a path from a certain point. 0 indicates the goal, -2 indicates an off limits section, and any other number indicates a distance from that spot to the goal (0). I've written 6 functions to populate surrounding neighbors. These functions feed into another function that populates the map.. or is supposed to. I find with certain inputs, the map population goes awry on the left portion. I've done a desk check and can't figure out why. Any fresh eyes would help greatly, I've been looking at this for some time:

```
       struct Point {
            int r;
            int c;
        };

        Queue <Point> q;

        Point getNeighbors1(int r, int c) {
        int n1r, n1c;

                if (r < (ROW-1) ) {
                    n1r = r+1;
                    n1c = c;

                    Point neighborLoc1;
                    neighborLoc1.r = n1r;
                    neighborLoc1.c = n1c;

                    return neighborLoc1;
                }
        }

        Point getNeighbors2(int r, int c) {
        int n2r, n2c;

                if (r > 0) {
                    n2r = r-1;
                    n2c = c;

                    Point neighborLoc2;
                    neighborLoc2.r = n2r;
                    neighborLoc2.c = n2c;

                    return neighborLoc2;
                }
        }

        Point g

etNeighbors3(int r, int c) {
    int n3r, n3c;

            if (c < (COL-1) ) {
                n3r = r;
                n3c = c+1;

                Point neighborLoc3;
                neighborLoc3.r = n3r;
                neighborLoc3.c = n3c;

                return neighborLoc3;
            }
    }

    Point getNeighbors4(int r, int c) {
    int n4r, n4c;


            if (c > 0) {
                n4r = r;
                n4c = c-1;

                Point neighborLoc4;
                neighborLoc4.r = n4r;
                neighborLoc4.c = n4c;

                return neighborLoc4;
            }
    }

    Point getNeighbors5(int r, int c) {
    int n5r, n5c;

        if (c % 2 == 0) {
            if (r > 0 && c < COL-1 ) {
                n5r = r-1;
                n5c = c+1;

                Point neighborLoc5;
                neighborLoc5.r = n5r;
                neighborLoc5.c = n5c;

                return neighborLoc5;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (r < (ROW-1) && c < (COL-1) ) {
                n5r = r+1;
                n5c = c+1;

                Point neighborLoc5;
                neighborLoc5.r = n5r;
                neighborLoc5.c = n5c;

                return neighborLoc5;
            }

        }

    }

    Point getNeighbors6(int r, int c) {
    int n6r, n6c;

        if (c % 2 == 0) {
            if (r > 0 && c > 0) {
                n6r = r-1;
                n6c = c-1;

                Point neighborLoc6;
                neighborLoc6.r = n6r;
                neighborLoc6.c = n6c;

                return neighborLoc6;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (r < (ROW-1) && c > 0) {
                n6r = r+1;
                n6c = c-1;

                Point neighborLoc6;
                neighborLoc6.r = n6r;
                neighborLoc6.c = n6c;

                return neighborLoc6;
            }
        }

    }

    //populate grid
    void numberScheme (Queue<Point> pQ, int map[ROW][COL]) {
        while (!pQ.isEmpty()) {

            Point p = pQ.dequeue();

            Point n1 = getNeighbors1(p.r, p.c);
            if (map[n1.r][n1.c] == -1) {
                map[n1.r][n1.c] = map[p.r][p.c] + 1;
                pQ.enqueue(n1);
            }

            Point n2 = getNeighbors2(p.r, p.c);
            if (map[n2.r][n2.c] == -1) {
                map[n2.r][n2.c] = map[p.r][p.c] + 1;
                pQ.enqueue(n2);
            }

            Point n3 = getNeighbors3(p.r, p.c);
            if (map[n3.r][n3.c] == -1) {
                map[n3.r][n3.c] = map[p.r][p.c] + 1;
                pQ.enqueue(n3);
            }

            Point n4 = getNeighbors4(p.r, p.c);
            if (map[n4.r][n4.c] == -1) {
                map[n4.r][n4.c] = map[p.r][p.c] + 1;
                pQ.enqueue(n4);
            }

            Point n5 = getNeighbors5(p.r, p.c);
            if (map[n5.r][n5.c] == -1) {
                map[n5.r][n5.c] = map[p.r][p.c] + 1;
                pQ.enqueue(n5);
            }

            Point n6 = getNeighbors6(p.r, p.c);
            if (map[n6.r][n6.c] == -1) {
                map[n6.r][n6.c] = map[p.r][p.c] + 1;
                pQ.enqueue(n6);
            }

        }
    }
```

some example input: goal is at (12, 12), off limits cell: (1, 19). And I get this mess:

```
 9  9 10 11 12 13 14 14 14 13 13 12 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 13 13 12 12 11 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 -2 
 9 10 10 11 12 13 13 12 12 11 11 10 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 
10 11 11 12 12 12 12 11 11 10 10  9  9  9 10 10 11 11 12 12 
11 12 12 12 12 11 11 10 10  9  9  8  8  8  9  9 10 10 11 11 
11 11 12 11 11 10 10  9  9  8  8  7  7  7  8  8  9  9 10 10 
10 10 11 10 10  9  9  8  8  7  7  6  6  6  7  7  8  8  9  9 
 9  9 10  9  9  8  8  7  7  6  6  5  5  5  6  6  7  7  8  8 
 8  9 10  9  8  7  7  6  6  5  5  4  4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7 
 8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  5  4  4  3  3  3  4  4  5  5  6  7 
 8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  3  2  2  2  3  3  4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  2  1  2  2  3  4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  4  3  3  2  3  3  4  4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10  9  8  7  6  6  5  5  4  4  3  4  4  5  5  6  6  7 
 9 10 10  9  8  8  7  7  6  6  5  5  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  8 
10 10 10 10  9  9  8  8  7  7  6  6  5  6  6  7  7  8  8  9 
 9  9 10 11 10 10  9  9  8  8  7  7  6  7  7  8  8  9  9 10 
 8  9 10 11 11 11 10 10  9  9  8  8  7  8  8  9  9 10 10 11
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the way you're calculating directions is off. You would probably do well to name them, instead of `getNeighborsx`, to `getNorthNeighbor`, `getSouthNeighbor`, `getNortheastNeighbor`, `getSouthwestNeighbor`, `getNorthwestNeighbor`, `getSoutheastNeighbor`, as that would make it easy to identify which functions are doing what and why they might not be behaving as expected.

When I made a hexagonal grid, I defined directions like this:

```
enum direction {
    north, south, northeast, southwest, northwest, southeast
};
```

And I got relative points from a direction like this:

```
point point::getRelativePoint(const direction & d) const {
    switch (d) {
    case north: return point(x + 1, y); //North and south are defined along the X axis, for our purposes
    case south: return point(x - 1, y);
    case northeast: return point(x, y + 1); //Northeast and Southwest are defined along the Y axis
    case southwest: return point(x, y - 1);
    case southeast: return point(x - 1, y + 1); //Northwest and Southeast can be defined by adding together other directions: Northwest is North + Southwest, and Southeast is South + Northeast.
    case northwest: return point(x + 1, y - 1);
    }
}
```

Your `getNeighbors5` and `getNeighbors6` functions are what I believe are at fault, because they change direction based on suspect criteria:

```
Point getNeighbors5(int r, int c) {
    int n5r, n5c;

    if (c % 2 == 0) {
        if (r > 0 && c < COL-1 ) {
            n5r = r-1;
            n5c = c+1;

            Point neighborLoc5;
            neighborLoc5.r = n5r;
            neighborLoc5.c = n5c;

            return neighborLoc5;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (r < (ROW-1) && c < (COL-1) ) {
            n5r = r+1;
            n5c = c+1;

            Point neighborLoc5;
            neighborLoc5.r = n5r;
            neighborLoc5.c = n5c;

            return neighborLoc5;
        }

    }
}
```

It doesn't make sense that you're changing which direction this is based on which column it's in. SouthEast of a cell (if it's defined as a composite of South and NorthEast) is always going to be -1, +1 of that cell.

I've attached an image of a hexagonal grid, I suggest you use it to work out the positions of these cells. Depending on how you've defined North/NorthEast, you may need to rotate the directions of the Axis' I provided, but it should illuminate where you might have gone wrong.

[image: image of hexagonal grid]

Comment: Would I really have to replace all my getNeighbor functions completely? I understand how the naming can be off but if I alter the directions (not based on column), do I have to use a switch statement

Comment: Only 5 and 6 would need to be replaced, as far as I'm concerned, since in the coordinate system I'm proposing, directions 1-4 still work, they just have to be assigned meaning. I used a switch statement for the purpose of making the code concise, but you're free to keep them as distinct functions. I just can't recommend using Offset Notation for addressing the cells, as it is incredibly difficult to debug.